# passing value fron conf.js to a grunt task or between grunt tasks

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, protractor

How do I pass information between `grunt` tasks? I would like to pass a value from a `grunt` task to another `grunt` task.

My situation is that after completing a protractor test, I would like to pass a value to a new `grunt` task. To achieve this, I went ahead and set the value in `process.env` and tried to use `process.env` in the new `grunt` task. But that doesn't seem to work

This is `conf.js`:

```
afterLaunch: function(exitCode) {
    return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
      if (typeof jasmine.getEnv().testReportFilePath !== 'undefined' && jasmine.getEnv().testReportFilePath !== null) {
        process.env.testReportFilePath = jasmine.getEnv().testReportFilePath;
        console.log('Trying: ' + process.env.testReportFilePath);
        fulfill('Success: Environment variable testReportFilePath is set in conf.js');
      } else {
        reject(new Error('Failed: Environment variable testReportFilePath not set in conf.js'));
      }
    });
```

And this is my `Gruntfile`:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-protractor-runner');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-protractor-webdriver');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-execute');

grunt.config('protractor', {
    require: [ setTesting ],
    options: {
      configFile: 'conf.js', // common config file
      keepAlive: true, // If false, the grunt process stops when the test fails.
      noColor: false // If true, protractor will not use colors in its output.
    },
    run_specific_suite: {
      options: {
        args: {
          baseUrl: '<%= grunt.option("testUrl") %>',
          browser: '<%= grunt.option("testBrowser") %>',
          params: {
            environment: '<%= grunt.option("testEnv") %>'
          },
          suite: '<%= grunt.option("testSuite") %>'
        }
      }
    },
});

grunt.config('execute', {
  email_stakeholders: {
    options: {
      args: [
        process.env.testReportFilePath,
        'myemail@email.com'
      ]
    },
    src: ['toDelete.js']
  }
});
```

But `process.env.testReportFilePath` appears to be `undefined` in the gruntjs file.

Comment: I cannot see the relationship between `conf.js` and your Gruntfile. When do you call `conf.js`? Can't you write the `testReportFilePath` variable to a file and let the Grunt task pick it up from there?

Comment: @mparnisari: **conf.js** is a protractor configuration file based on the following: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/example/conf.js, which is run using grunt task plugin: **grunt-protractor-runner**. I will update the OP to include the grunt-protractor-run task as well.

Comment: @mparnisari: I did not want to persist and deal with destroying the value. But is that how values are passed around in grunt tasks?

Comment: No, I think the most common way to do this is just use a shared variable. The problem in your case is that Grunt and Protractor might be running in different processes

Answer (score 0):

This answer is long overdue. I did follow @mparnisari suggestion to write the variable out to the file. So I did the following in my conf.js to write the value into a yaml file :

`fs.writeFileSync(path.join(process.cwd(),'_testReportFilePath.yml'),
                         'testReportFilePath: ' + jasmine.getEnv().testReportFilePath);`

and in the `gruntfile`, the yaml file read using the grunt api :

```
// --- grunt execute task  --- //
  grunt.config('execute', {
    email_stakeholders: {
      options: {
        args:[
          grunt.file.readYAML(path.join(process.cwd(),'_testReportFilePath.yml')).testReportFilePath, // html report
          'myemail@email.com'//enter the recipient emails here
        ]
      },
      src: ['test/scripts/nightlyPostTasks.js']
    }
  });
```

and appears to do what I need. Only quirk is that a dummy yaml file with the name `_testReportFilePath.yml` must always be present in `CWD` to prevent any grunt error.